# peepopen - macvim - reindex

Tags: vim, macvim

I am using the peepopen plugin for Macvim.

However, when I create a new file within my Macvim session, it is not visible in peepopen. It is still the original snapshot from when I originally opened Macvim.

Is there a way to reindex Peepopen? Currently the only way for me to reindex the project is to reopen peepopen.

Answer (score 2):

With the Peepopen panel open in Macvim, pressing ⌘ + r will reload/reindex files.

Or, again with the panel open, click on the cog at the top right and select ‘Reload files’.